# Multicollinearity in Logistic Regression - chi-sq tests vs correlation matrix (corrb in SAS)

Tags: logistic, correlation, multicollinearity, chi-squared-test

I have categorical variables (some 0/1, some nominal and some ordinal) and I'm getting different answers when using the two different approaches for deciding if there's multicollinearity.  To get the correlation matrix, I have to use dummy variables.  But I can do the chi-square test on the actual values of the categorical variables.  It seems like this difference might cause some differences betw the results of the chi-sq test and of using correl (for example, if it's close to the threshold), but the differences are much beyond this.

What's a good rule of thumb for the correlation approach, to consider getting rid of a variable when it's correlated > 70% with another variable?  Would that be about the same as using a threshold of 5% for the chi-square test between those two variables?

Correlation betw age & gender (both dichotomous) is 0.084 while the chi-square test gives 0.023, so we reject the null and conclude that there is a signif relationship.  What am I doing wrong?  In total, I have no correlations above 70% but the chi-square test says I have a signif association in 10 of 15 pairs.

I must be misunderstanding something.

Thank you!